# Pyopencl: difference between to_device and Buffer

Tags: python, numpy, opencl, pyopencl

Let

```
import pyopencl as cl
import pyopencl.array as cl_array
import numpy
a = numpy.random.rand(50000).astype(numpy.float32)
mf = cl.mem_flags
```

What is the difference between

```
a_gpu = cl.Buffer(self.ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a)
```

and

```
a_gpu = cl_array.to_device(self.ctx, self.queue, a)
```

?

And what is the difference between

```
result =  numpy.empty_like(a)
cl.enqueue_copy(self.queue, result, result_gpu)
```

and

```
result = result_gpu.get()
```

?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Buffers are CL's version of `malloc`, while `pyopencl.array.Array` is a workalike of numpy arrays on the compute device.

So for the second version of the first part of your question, you may write `a_gpu + 2` to get a new arrays that has 2 added to each number in your array, whereas in the case of the `Buffer`, PyOpenCL only sees a bag of bytes and cannot perform any such operation.

The second part of your question is the same in reverse: If you've got a PyOpenCL array, `.get()` copies the data back and converts it into a (host-based) numpy array. Since numpy arrays are one of the more convenient ways to get contiguous memory in Python, the second variant with `enqueue_copy` also ends up in a numpy array--but note that you could've copied this data into an array of any size (as long as it's big enough) and any type--the copy is performed as a bag of bytes, whereas `.get()` makes sure you get the same size and type on the host.

Bonus fact: There is of course a Buffer underlying each PyOpenCL array. You can get it from the `.data` attribute.

Comment: I've just realized that you are the author of PyOpenCL. Thanks a lot for PyOpenCL and for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

To answer the first question, `Buffer(hostbuf=...)` can be called with anything that implements the [buffer interface](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html)  ([reference](http://www.training.prace-ri.eu/uploads/tx_pracetmo/LinkSCEMM_pyOpenCL.pdf)).  `pyopencl.array.to_device(...)` must be called with an `ndarray` ([reference](http://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/array.html)).  `ndarray` implements the buffer interface and works in either place.  However, only `hostbuf=...` would be expected to work with for example a `bytearray` (which also implements the buffer interface).  I have not confirmed this, but it appears to be what the docs suggest.

On the second question, I am not sure what type `result_gpu` is supposed to be when you call `get()` on it (did you mean `Buffer.get_host_array()`?)  In any case, `enqueue_copy()` works between combination of `Buffer`, `Image` and `host`, can have offsets and regions, and can be asynchronous (with `is_blocking=False`), and I think these capabilities are only available that way (whereas `get()` would be blocking and return the whole buffer). ([reference](http://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/runtime.html#transfers))