# Does Numpy automatically detect and use GPU?

Tags: python, numpy, gpu

I have a few basic questions about using Numpy with GPU (nvidia GTX 1080 Ti).  I'm new to GPU, and would like to make sure I'm properly using the GPU to accelerate Numpy/Python.  I searched on the internet for a while, but didn't find a simple tutorial that addressed my questions.  I'd appreciate it if someone can give me some pointers:

1) Does Numpy/Python automatically detect the presence of GPU and utilize it to speed up matrix computation (e.g. numpy.multiply, numpy.linalg.inv, ... etc)?  Or do I have code in a specific way to exploit the GPU for fast computation?

2) Can someone recommend a good tutorial/introductory material on using Numpy/Python with GPU (nvidia's)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can probably compile numpy with a math library that detects GPU, but I don't think it's something numpy offers on it's own.

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> Does Numpy/Python automatically detect the presence of GPU and utilize
> it to speed up matrix computation (e.g. numpy.multiply,
> numpy.linalg.inv, ... etc)?

No.

> Or do I have code in a specific way to exploit the GPU for fast
> computation?

Yes. Search for Numba, CuPy, Theano, PyTorch or PyCUDA for different paradigms for accelerating Python with GPUs.

Comment: As a reference, https://stsievert.com/blog/2016/07/01/numpy-gpu/ is a blog entry from the ancient days (2016), but is updated consistently.

Comment: I'm curious, picamera2 enables images in np arrays. is it straight forward to compare 3D npArrays containinf RGB_A data using GPU enabled libs like the ones you mentioned? or will it imply intermediate transformations?

Answer (score 18):

No, you can also use CuPy which has a similar interface with numpy. https://cupy.chainer.org/

Answer (score 13):

No. Numpy does not use GPU. But you can use CuPy. The syntax of CuPy is quite compatible with NumPy. So, to use GPU, You just need to replace the following line  of your code

```
 import numpy as np
```

with

```
import cupy as np
```

That's all. Go ahead and run your code. One more thing that I think I should mention here is that to install CuPy you first need to install CUDA. Since the objective of your question is to make your computations faster by making use of GPU, I would also suggest you explore PyTorch. With PyTorch, you can do almost everything that you can do with NumPy and much more. The learning curve would also be quite smooth if you are already familiar with NumPy. You can find more details on replacing NumPy with PyTorch here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3iYN-2XL8w

Comment: btw, they are not perfectly equivalent, and cupy works well only with cuda, it's not guarantee anything on other GPUs

Answer (score 7):

JAX uses XLA to compile NumPy code to run on GPUs/ TPUs : https://github.com/google/jax

Answer (score 0):

## No need for CUDA

If your GPU doesn't support CUDA, it seems that you can use [PyOpenCL](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/).

As far as know, its quite NumPy-compatible syntax works something like this:

```py
import pyopencl as cl
import pyopencl.array as cl_array
import numpy as np

platform = cl.get_platforms()[0]
device = platform.get_devices()[0]
context = cl.Context([device])
queue = cl.CommandQueue(context)

N = 10000 # array size

# Create array in main memory
a_cpu = np.random.rand(N,N).astype(np.float32)

# Compute on CPU: slow
result_from_cpu = a_cpu**100

# Copy to GPU, compute on GPU, fetch result from GPU: fast
a_gpu = cl_array.to_device(queue, a_cpu)
result_from_gpu = a_gpu**100
result_from_gpu_copied_to_main_memory = result_from_gpu.get()
```

A less NumPy-specific alternative to `pyopencl.array` is `pyopencl.Buffer`, see [Pyopencl: difference between to_device and Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396443/pyopencl-difference-between-to-device-and-buffer)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [**TensorFlow**](https://www.tensorflow.org/) if you have a CUDA GPU.

Like some of the other answers (Theano, PyTorch, JAX), TensorFlow is primarily used for machine learning, but it supports most array operations from NumPy.

There's also Theano's fork [**Aesara**](https://github.com/aesara-devs/aesara) and its fork [**PyTensor**](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pytensor).