# compute multiple images in parallel using numpy

Tags: python, parallel-processing, gpu, numba

I am generating super random binary images and I am doing that on one CPU core atm. Since I want to generate millions of images, I need to do this on my CUDA GPU. I think numba is the right tool to use, but which of its features? I would like to compute each image on a different GPGPU core, so my main process on the CPU should just copy the image info (basically only the id) and generate as many images as possible parallel on the GPGPU cores.

I thought about using `jit` but I am not sure if it suits my needs and that is why I want to hear some experts on the topic.

The code is fairly simple, I want to parallel execute

```
import numpy as np

def gen_img(id):
    np.random.seed(id)
    a = np.random.randint(2, size=(1080, 1080))
    return a
```

Does `numba.jit` suits my needs?

Comment: this is covered by this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605231/does-numpy-automatically-detect-and-use-gpu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Numpy automatically detect and use GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605231/does-numpy-automatically-detect-and-use-gpu)

Comment: No, this does not answer my question. I do not want to speed up the numpy code but distribute the code to each GPU "node" and execute it there.

Comment: Numba doesn't allow numpy functions to run on the GPU

Answer (score -1):

> **Q** : *"Does `numba.jit` suit my needs?"*

No. Given your aim is to have a high-performance production of a *"just"*-**`[CONCURRENT]`** workflow of generating 1080 x 1080 bitmaps
(at random - which is a topic of its own), neither the python, not the `numba.jit`-accelerated code will perform anywhere near a right-enough, low-level CUDA-optimised code.

A quality of the PRNG-produced randomness, based on a centrally dispatched seed-**`id`** is a core problem here, not the GPU-hosted production code + a few file-I/O.

The problem of achieving high quality distribution mapping between the seed-`id` and PRNG-produced goes well beyond the Stack Overflow Q/A site and belongs to the field of cryptography, not the PRNG implementation. If interested in using smart, high quality PRNG-s composable as CUDA-kernels ( i.e. not depending on the limits of the GPU-hardware for not very deep (quite *shallow* and often without published properties of the produced distributions of the PRNG numbers, compared to other PRNG-s, incl. those with the published source-codes ) random vectors of bits, there are many posts to start from here.

### An inspiration for using the right-enough tools :

As an example, one may source such bitmaps from shell directly, having whatever degree of parallelism of jobs fits the hardware-contraints, without ever calling a GIL-lock dancing Python interpreter:

```
$ seq 4096 | parallel --jobs 32 \
                      --bar      \
                      '(base64 -w0 /dev/urandom | head -c 145800 > random_data_1k80_1k80_1bit.{})'
```

Adding file-format specific header to the raw-data or sending raw-data over a pipe / socket to some other process is easy and obvious, using the right tools. Isn't that great?